# Inserindo registro e recuperando ID gerado pelo SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-insert

Quero inserir um registro em uma tabela, recuperar o ID que foi gerado pelo `AUTO_INCREMENT` e inserir registros em outras tabelas, usando esse ID. Mas, quero fazer isso tudo usando o `BeginTransaction`.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
    public void venda(Venda_ResumidaModel objVenda)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("SERVER= ;" + "DATABASE= ;" + "UID= ;" + "PASSWORD=;"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction = null;

            try
            {
                // BeginTransaction() Requires Open Connection
                connection.Open();

                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                // Assign Transaction to Command
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                // Execute 1st Command
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Venda(ID_Pessoa, ID_Caixa, ID_PDV, ID_Deposito, Data, Itens, Valor, Desconto, Valor_Final, Cancelada, Valor_Dinheiro, Valor_Cheque, Valor_Cartao, Valor_Crediario, Valor_Troco) " +
                "values (@ID_Pessoa, @ID_Caixa, @ID_PDV, @ID_Deposito, getdate(), @Itens, @Valor, @Desconto, @Valor_Final, @Cancelada, @Valor_Dinheiro, @Valor_Cheque, @Valor_Cartao, @Valor_Crediario, @Valor_Troco)";


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Pessoa", objVenda.ObjProprietario.ID_Pessoa);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Caixa", objVenda.ObjCaixa.ID_Caixa);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_PDV", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Deposito", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itens", objVenda.Itens);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor", objVenda.Valor_Venda);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desconto", objVenda.Desconto);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Final", objVenda.Valor_final);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cancelada", 'N');
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Dinheiro", objVenda.Valor_dinheiro);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Cheque", objVenda.Valor_cheque);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Cartao", objVenda.Valor_cartao);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Crediario", objVenda.Valor_crediario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Troco", objVenda.Valor_troco);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteScalar();


                // Execute 2nd Command
            if (objVenda.Valor_dinheiro > 0)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Caixa_Movimentacao (Caixa, Data_Movimentacao, Tipo, Valor, Forma_Pagamento)" +
                    "values (@Caixa, getdate(), 6, @Valor_, 1)";


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caixa", objVenda.ObjCaixa.ID_Caixa);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_", objVenda.ValorVenda);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }





            int retorno = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value);

            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Venda_Item_Servico (Id_venda, ID_Servico, Valor_Venda, Desconto, Valor_Total) values ("+ retorno +", @ID_Servico, @Valor_Venda, @Desconto, @Valor_Total)";
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", objVenda);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Servico", objVenda.ObjServico.Codigo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Venda", objVenda.ObjServico.Valor_Venda);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desconto", objVenda);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor_Total", objVenda.ObjServico.Valor_Venda);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transaction.Commit();

            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: coloquei na pergunta o que eu fiz

Comment: Qual banco está usando?

Comment: estou usando o SQL

Comment: Qual banco de dados? SQL é genérico.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vai mudar a *query* para (o `OUTPUT` está no meio):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Venda(ID_Pessoa, ID_Caixa, ID_PDV, ID_Deposito, Data,
     Itens, Valor, Desconto, Valor_Final, Cancelada, Valor_Dinheiro, Valor_Cheque, 
     Valor_Cartao, Valor_Crediario, Valor_Troco)
     OUTPUT INSERTED.ID 
     values (@ID_Pessoa, @ID_Caixa, @ID_PDV, @ID_Deposito, getdate(), @Itens, @Valor, 
    @Desconto, @Valor_Final, @Cancelada, @Valor_Dinheiro, @Valor_Cheque, @Valor_Cartao, 
     @Valor_Crediario, @Valor_Troco)";
```

E vai executá-la assim:

```
var IdInserido = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

De acordo com o Giovanni Machado em comentário abaixo. Este código pode ter problemas se houver um gatilho configurado para tabela. neste caso seria melhor usar

```
SELECT scope_identity()
```

ou

```
Set @Id_Out = @@IDENTITY
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/GetIdInserted.cs).

Comment: Quando executa me retorna esse erro:

Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.

Comment: @Lilloh Oops, coloquei no lugar errado.

Comment: Deu certo a unica coisa que tiver que alterar foi a conversão.

var IdInserido = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Para: var idVenda = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: @bigown é possível o retorno através do  `Set @Id_Out = @@IDENTITY`  certo, agora fiquei na duvida do `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` , qual a diferença?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Basta colocar esta linha e resolve igual? Não precisa de mais nada, não funciona só em circunstâncias específicas? Não sei, pode ser. Mas a forma que postei parece ser bem segura que vai funcionar sempre. Se souber de vantagem desta forma, me avise :)

Comment: @bigown, Sim basta colocar o  `@@IDENTITY` ele tem o valor da última  identidade inserida. acredito que nesse caso seria a mesma coisa como ele que o valor do id inserido... [ https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187342(v=sql.120).aspx ]

Comment: @bigown @MarconcilioSouza o comando `output inserted.id` não funciona caso a tabela tenha uma trigger, se a tabela possuir uma trigger será necessário a utilização do código `SELECT scope_identity()` ou do `Set @Id_Out = @@IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 3):

Você não falou qual banco de dados está utilizando, mas caso esteja utilizando o PostgreSQL altere a sua query para:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Venda(ID_Pessoa, ID_Caixa, ID_PDV, ID_Deposito, Data, Itens, Valor, Desconto, Valor_Final, Cancelada, Valor_Dinheiro, Valor_Cheque, Valor_Cartao, Valor_Crediario, Valor_Troco) " +
                "values (@ID_Pessoa, @ID_Caixa, @ID_PDV, @ID_Deposito, getdate(), @Itens, @Valor, @Desconto, @Valor_Final, @Cancelada, @Valor_Dinheiro, @Valor_Cheque, @Valor_Cartao, @Valor_Crediario, @Valor_Troco) RETURNING ID_Pessoa";
```

Comment: Estou usando o Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: A resposta do @bigown é a melhor nesse caso.

Answer (score 2):

Como você está usando o [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx), você pode adicionar na sua consulta/inserção um select `MAX(ID_Venda)` logo após o insert e será retornado um `object` com o valor.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Venda(
    ID_Pessoa, ID_Caixa, ID_PDV, ID_Deposito, Data, Itens, Valor, 
    Desconto, Valor_Final, Cancelada, Valor_Dinheiro, Valor_Cheque,
    Valor_Cartao, Valor_Crediario, Valor_Troco
)
VALUES (
    @ID_Pessoa, @ID_Caixa, @ID_PDV, @ID_Deposito, getdate(), 
    @Itens, @Valor, @Desconto, @Valor_Final, @Cancelada, @Valor_Dinheiro,
    @Valor_Cheque, @Valor_Cartao, @Valor_Crediario, @Valor_Troco);
SELECT MAX(ID_Venda) FROM Venda";
```

Para obter o ID retornado

```
var idVenda = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Testei aqui e deu certo.

Comment: @Lilloh acho que a maneira mostrada pelo @bigown é mais "correta". Também não sabia do `OUTPUT`.

Comment: eu também não sabia utilizar.. to usando a dele porque eu não quero dar um sql para "pegar" o código.

Comment: ao invés de fazer `SELECT MAX(ID_Venda) FROM Venda` vc pode fazer `select @@identity`