# Qual a diferença e as vantagens em usar @@IDENTITY e OUTPUT INSERTED.ID

Tags: sql-server, return, identity-server

Sempre usei o `@@IDENTITY` para obter o último valor de identidade inserido, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
create Proc [dbo].[Arquivos]
  @IdArquivo int,
  @IdArquivo_Out int output
as
begin
  Set Xact_Abort on
  Set Nocount on
  Begin Tran

  begin
    Insert into tb_Arquivos (IdArquivo, DtInclusao)
    values (@IdArquivo, GETDATE()
     )
    Set @IdArquivo_Out = @@IDENTITY
  Commit
end
```

mas vendo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99816/inserindo-registro-e-recuperando-id-gerado-pelo-sql-server-2012/99820?noredirect=1#comment203240_99820) esses dias fiquei na duvida com o uso do `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID`.

Existe alguma diferença entre os dois em termo de desempenho ou alguma diferença para uso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem 5 métodos para obter o último ID inserido, são eles:

- @@IDENTITY
- SCOPE_IDENTITY()
- IDENT_CURRENT('nome da tabela aqui')
- OUTPUT
- SELECT MAX

Abaixo cada um explorado de maneira breve.

## @@IDENTITY

Retorna o último ID gerado na sessão atual do usuário. Esse ID pode ter sido gerado por um comando INSERT explícito dado pelo usuário ou indiretamente por uma trigger que tenha sido executada dentro da mesma sessão. Tem que ficar atento ao utilizá-lo.

## SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Retorna o último ID gerado dentro do escopo atual. O escopo atual pode ser uma stored procedure, trigger ou um INSERT explícito que tenha sido dado pelo usuário. Esta é uma maneira mais garantida de saber o último ID gerado do que @@IDENTITY, já que evita-se IDs que eventualmente tenham sido gerados por triggers executadas indiretamente.

## IDENT_CURRENT()

Esta função retorna o último ID gerado para a tabela passada como parâmetro. Tomar cuidado, pois tem gente que já escreveu dizendo que esse método não é *transaction-safe*.

[For the last time, NO, you can't trust IDENT_CURRENT()](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current)

## OUTPUT

O método OUTPUT é relativamente recente (creio que a partir do SQL Server 2005). Para obter o último registro com ele basta utilizar **OUTPUT INSERTED.ID**. Como exemplificado aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99820/3084

Ele é bem poderoso, pois além de permitir saber o último ID inserido, permite que informações do registro incluído sejam inseridas em outra tabela, isso tudo com uma sintaxe enxuta e bem clara. Veja um exemplo retirado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/26400584/2236741

```
INSERT INTO [User] (ID, Email)
OUTPUT inserted.id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO user_log(id, date)
VALUES (1, 'a@x.com'), (2, 'b@x.com');
```

Note que um registro está sendo inserido na tabela **User** e no próprio OUTPUT insere-se outro na tabela **User_Log**.

## SELECT MAX

Este método consiste em realizar um SELECT MAX(CAMPO_ID) FROM TABELA. Ele não é indicado quando se está inserindo um registro, pois gasta-se um SQL a mais para saber uma informação que pode ser obtida das formas mostradas acima. Além disso, se o valor do campo ID não for um Inteiro (um GUID, por exemplo), então este método falhará.