# Como obter a primary key identity de um registro inserido?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-insert, stored-procedures

Preciso criar uma `stored procedure` para inserir um jogo no meu banco de dados. Um jogo se relaciona com um campeonato através da tabela `campeonatoJogo`.

As tabelas são basicamente:

```
create table jogo(
  codJogo int identity primary key,
  nomeTime1 varchar(50) not null,
  nomeTime2 varchar(50) not null,
  partida1 varchar(5) null,
  partida2 varchar(5) null,
  partida3 varchar(5) null,
  mapa1 varchar(50) null,
  mapa2 varchar(50) null,
  mapa3 varchar(50) null,
  timeVencedor varchar(50) null,
  data datetime not null
)

create table campeonato (
  codCampeonato int primary key identity,
  nome varchar(200) not null,
  dataInicio date not null,
  dataFim date null 
)

create table campeonatoJogo(
  codCampeonatoJogo int identity primary key,
  codCampeonato int not null,
  codJogo int not null,
  constraint fkCodJogo foreign key(codJogo) references jogo(codJogo),
  constraint fkCodCampeonato2 foreign key(codCampeonato) references campeonato(codCampeonato)
)
```

Na hora de eu inserir o jogo, eu quero que passando as informações do jogo e o código do campeonato eu consiga fazer o relacionamento das tabelas na `stored procedure` abaixo, ela portanto insere um jogo num determinado campeonato.

```
-- Insere um jogo num determinado campeonato
create proc insertJogo_sp
    @nomeTime1 varchar(50),
    @nomeTime2 varchar(50),
    @partida1 varchar(5),
    @partida2 varchar(5),
    @partida3 varchar(5),
    @mapa1    varchar(50),
    @mapa2    varchar(50),
    @mapa3    varchar(50),
    @timeVencedor varchar(50),
    @data datetime,
    @codCampeonato int
as
    if not exists (select * from campeonato where codCampeonato=@codCampeonato)
        print 'Não existe o campeonato que você deseja inserir o jogo'
    else
    begin
        insert into jogo values(@nomeTime1, @nomeTime2,
                                @partida1, @partida2, @partida3, 
                                @mapa1, @mapa2, @mapa3, 
                                @timeVencedor, @data)

        declare @codJogo int
        /* como obter o codJogo (primary key) do jogo que eu inseri
           para inserir na tabela campeonatoJogo?
           * codJogo é identity, portanto não estou passando como parâmetro da stored procedure
        */
        select @codJogo=? from


        insert into campeonatoJogo values(@codCampeonato, @codJogo)
    end
```

Eu queria saber como eu faria para pegar o `codJogo` que é `primary key identity` do meu `insert` e assim inserindo no `campeonatoJogo`.
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Gostaria de sugerir que o autor da pergunta alterasse-a para `Como obter a primary key identity de um registro inserido?` para facilitar a identificação do tópico por pessoas com dúvidas semelhantes

Comment: @Sorack, na realidade você nem precisar solicitar, se a descrição da pergunta não convêm com a descrição do titulo, você pode editar com uma descrição que seja mais útil para a comunidade,  (Criando uma stored procedure) , realmente não é um bom titulo nesse caso.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza alterado então

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença e as vantagens em usar @@IDENTITY e OUTPUT INSERTED.ID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100100/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-e-as-vantagens-em-usar-identity-e-output-inserted-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem algumas formas para se obter o ID do seu ultimo `insert`, como o `@@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), IDENT_CURRENT('nome da tabela aqui')OUTPUT e o SELECT MAX.`

No seu caso o uso do `@@IDENTITY` ou `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` são os mais eficazes. [Veja aqui a descrição de cada um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100100/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-e-as-vantagens-em-usar-identity-e-output-inserted-id/100115#100115). Eu utilizo geralmente o `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` por ser uma maneira mais garantida de saber o último ID gerado do que `@@IDENTITY`.

Veja como ficaria sua proc.

```
-- Insere um jogo num determinado campeonato
create proc insertJogo_sp
    @nomeTime1 varchar(50),
    @nomeTime2 varchar(50),
    @partida1 varchar(5),
    @partida2 varchar(5),
    @partida3 varchar(5),
    @mapa1    varchar(50),
    @mapa2    varchar(50),
    @mapa3    varchar(50),
    @timeVencedor varchar(50),
    @data datetime,
    @codCampeonato int
as
    if not exists (select * from campeonato where codCampeonato=@codCampeonato)
        print 'Não existe o campeonato que você deseja inserir o jogo'
    else
    begin
        insert into jogo values(@nomeTime1, @nomeTime2,
                                @partida1, @partida2, @partida3, 
                                @mapa1, @mapa2, @mapa3, 
                                @timeVencedor, @data)

        declare @codJogo int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        insert into campeonatoJogo values(@codCampeonato, @codJogo)
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

**`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`**

Você só precisa da seguinte linha pra atribuir o código que foi inserido:

```
SET @codJogo = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

> [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Retorna o último valor de identidade inserido em uma coluna de identidade no mesmo escopo. Um escopo é um módulo: um procedimento armazenado, gatilho, função ou lote. Portanto, duas instruções estarão no mesmo escopo se eles estiverem no mesmo procedimento armazenado, função ou lote.
>
> **Aplica-se a:** SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 até a versão atual), Banco de dados SQL do Azure.

---

**`OUTPUT`**

Você também pode utilizar a cláusula `OUTPUT` da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @novosJogos table(codJogo INT);
DECLARE @codJogo INT;

INSERT INTO jogo(nomeTime1,
                 nomeTime2,
                 partida1,
                 partida2,
                 partida3,
                 mapa1,
                 mapa2,
                 mapa3,
                 timeVencedor,
                 data)
OUTPUT INSERTED.codJogo
  INTO @novosJogos
VALUES(@nomeTime1,
       @nomeTime2,
       @partida1,
       @partida2,
       @partida3,
       @mapa1,
       @mapa2,
       @mapa3,
       @timeVencedor,
       @data);

SELECT @codJogo = codJogo
  FROM @novosJogos;
```

> [Cláusula OUTPUT](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Retorna informações ou expressões baseadas em cada linha afetada por uma instrução `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` ou `MERGE`. Esses resultados podem ser retornados ao aplicativo de processamento para uso em mensagens de confirmação, arquivamentos e outros requisitos similares de aplicativo. Os resultados também podem ser inseridos em uma tabela ou variável de tabela. Além disso, você pode capturar os resultados de uma cláusula `OUTPUT` em uma instrução `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` ou `MERGE` aninhada e inserir esses resultados em uma tabela ou exibição de destino.
>
> **Aplica-se a:** SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 até a versão atual), Banco de dados SQL do Azure.

---

**`IDENT_CURRENT`**

Você pode utilizar a função `IDENT_CURRENT` que irá retornar o último valor de `IDENTITY` gerado para a tabela informada. Eu desaconselho este método já que pode acontecer do valor ser gerado por outra execução em paralelo, resultando em um valor incorreto.

```
DECLARE @codJogo INT;
...
SET @codJogo = IDENT_CURRENT('jogo');
```

> [`IDENT_CURRENT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Retorna o valor da última identidade gerado para uma tabela ou exibição especificada. O valor da última identidade gerado pode ser para qualquer sessão e para qualquer escopo.
>
> **Aplica-se a:** SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 até a versão atual), Banco de dados SQL do Azure.

---

**`@@IDENTITY`**

Após a conclusação de uma instrução `INSERT`, `SELECT INTO` ou de cópia em massa, `@@IDENTITY` conterá o último valor de identidade gerado pela instrução. Porém note que isto é independente de escopo ou sessão, portanto execuções em paralelo irão afetar a variável da mesma forma, podendo resultar em um resultado incorreto para o fim deseado.

```
DECLARE @codJogo INT;
...
SET @codJogo = @@IDENTITY;
```

> [`@@IDENTITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> É uma função de sistema que retorna o último valor de identidade inserido.
>
> **Aplica-se a:** SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 até a versão atual), Banco de dados SQL do Azure.