# C# e Sql Server, inserindo com proc usando BEGIN TRAN

Tags: c#, sql-server, orientação-a-objetos

Boa noite!

Estou inserindo um registro usando o *C# e Windows forms*, estou usando uma proc que insere em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo, o código está funcionando, mas, criei uma regra que a loja só pode ter apenas 1 gerente, joguei um select na proc para poder usar como retorno e usar o *cmd.ExecuteEscalar (c#)*, porem, ele insere na tabela e ainda me joga um erro na tela

> ( Erro Violação da restrição UNIQUE KEY 'UQ_TblPessoa_Cpf'. Não é
>   possível inserir a chave duplicada no objeto 'dbo.TblPessoa'. O valor
>   de chave duplicada é (22$%#@).

Não é possível inserir o valor `NULL` na coluna `Id_Pessoa`, tabela `'DB_BANCO_DE_HORAS.dbo.TblFuncionario';` a coluna não permite nulos. Falha em INSERT.) mas se eu olha no banco o registro consta , inclusive com o idGerente. espero que tenha ficado claro :-)

código da proc;

```
  ALTER PROC PR_INSERIR_PESSOA_E_FUNCIONARIO
    --pessoas 
    @Cpf varchar(11),
    @Nome varchar(60),
    @sexo char(1),
    --Funcionario
    @funcao varchar(30),
    @IdGerente int,
    @idLoja int
    as  
        DECLARE @X TABLE (IdPessoa INT)
        DECLARE @CONT INT = 0

        --VALIDANDO SE TEM GERENTE CADASTRADO NA LOJA
        IF(@funcao = 'GERENTE')     
            SET @CONT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TblFuncionario WHERE Id_Loja = @idLoja)

        IF(@CONT <= 0)
        BEGIN       

            BEGIN TRAN

            INSERT INTO TblPessoa (Cpf,Nome,Sexo)
            --essa linha vai pegar o idPessoa que é gerado pelo identity e seta na table @x, no campo da tabela idPessoa
            output inserted.Id_Pessoa into @X
            VALUES
            (@Cpf,@Nome,@sexo)

            if(@IdGerente = '')
                set @IdGerente = null;

            INSERT INTO TblFuncionario (Id_Pessoa,Funcao,Id_Gerente,Ativo,Id_Loja, DataContrato)
            VALUES
            ( (SELECT IdPessoa FROM @X),@funcao,@IdGerente,1,@idLoja,GETDATE())

            IF @@ERROR = 0
                COMMIT
            ELSE
                ROLLBACK    

            select IdPessoa from @X
        END


    GO
```

C#

```
public bool InserirFuncionario (Funcionario funcionario)
        {
            int idpessoa = 0;
            bool cadastro = false;
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = ConexaoBancoSQLServer.Conectar();

            cmd.CommandText = "PR_INSERIR_PESSOA_E_FUNCIONARIO";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cpf", funcionario.cpf);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", funcionario.nome);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", funcionario.sexo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@funcao", funcionario.funcao);

            if(funcionario.id_Gerente.ToString() != "")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdGerente", funcionario.id_Gerente);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idLoja", funcionario.id_Loja);


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            try
            {
                idpessoa = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                cadastro = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }                        
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Connection.Close();

            return cadastro;

        }


private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();


                funcionario.nome = txtNome.Text;
                funcionario.cpf = txtCpf.Text;
                funcionario.funcao = cmbFuncao.Text;
                funcionario.id_Loja = Convert.ToInt32(cmbLoja.SelectedValue);

                if(cmbGerente.Text != "")
                    funcionario.id_Gerente = FuncionarioGerenteCombo.func.id_Func;


                if (rdtFeminino.Checked == true || rdtMasculino.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (rdtFeminino.Checked == true)
                        funcionario.sexo = "F";
                    else
                        funcionario.sexo = "M";
                }


                if (funcionarioNegocio.InserirFuncionario(funcionario))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Funcionário cadastrado com sucesso!");

                    DialogResult resultado = MessageBox.Show("Deseja Cadastrar outro funcionário?", "Pergunta", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                    if (resultado == DialogResult.No)
                        LimparCampos();
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro");





            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + erro.Message);
            }


        }

namespace ObjetoTransferencia
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        public int id_Pessoa { get; set; }
        public string cpf { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string sexo { get; set; }

    }
}


namespace ObjetoTransferencia
{
    public class Funcionario : Pessoa
    {
        public int id_Func { get; set; }
        public string funcao { get; set; }
        public int id_Gerente { get; set; }
        public bool ativo { get; set; }
        public int id_Loja { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: a linha do erro está no NegocioFuncionario
idpessoa = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Comment: o erro acontece no ExecuteScalar porque é erro do banco de dados, apenas erro de violação de chave, verifique a sua procedure e os dados que estão sendo ou tentando inserir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, consegui resolver essa regra implantando uma trigger e alterando a proc

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_VALIDAR_GERENTE

ON TblFuncionario

FOR INSERT, UPDATE

AS

DECLARE @FUNC VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT Funcao FROM inserted)

DECLARE @COUNT int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TblFuncionario WHERE Funcao = 'GERENTE' and Id_Loja = (select Id_Loja from inserted))

IF(@FUNC = 'GERENTE' AND @COUNT > 1)
    ROLLBACK

CREATE PROC PR_INSERIR_PESSOA_E_FUNCIONARIO

--pessoas 

@Cpf varchar(11),
@Nome varchar(60),
@sexo char(1),

--Funcionario

@funcao varchar(30),
@IdGerente int,
@idLoja int
as  
DECLARE @X TABLE (IdPessoa INT)

BEGIN TRAN

    INSERT INTO TblPessoa (Cpf,Nome,Sexo)
    --essa linha vai pegar o idPessoa que é gerado pelo identity e seta na table @x, no campo da tabela idPessoa
    output inserted.Id_Pessoa into @X
    VALUES
    (@Cpf,@Nome,@sexo)

    if(@IdGerente = '')
        set @IdGerente = null;

    INSERT INTO TblFuncionario (Id_Pessoa,Funcao,Id_Gerente,Ativo,Id_Loja, DataContrato)
    VALUES
    ( (SELECT IdPessoa FROM @X),@funcao,@IdGerente,1,@idLoja,GETDATE())

IF @@ERROR = 0
    COMMIT
ELSE
    ROLLBACK
```

E pequenas alterações no C#

```
public void InserirFuncionario (Funcionario funcionario)
    {

        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = ConexaoBancoSQLServer.Conectar();

        cmd.CommandText = "PR_INSERIR_PESSOA_E_FUNCIONARIO";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cpf", funcionario.cpf);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", funcionario.nome);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", funcionario.sexo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@funcao", funcionario.funcao);

        if(funcionario.id_Gerente.ToString() != "")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdGerente", funcionario.id_Gerente);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idLoja", funcionario.id_Loja);


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Connection.Close();



    }



private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        try
        {
            Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();


            funcionario.nome = txtNome.Text;
            funcionario.cpf = txtCpf.Text;
            funcionario.funcao = cmbFuncao.Text;
            funcionario.id_Loja = Convert.ToInt32(cmbLoja.SelectedValue);

            if(cmbGerente.Text != "")
                funcionario.id_Gerente = FuncionarioGerenteCombo.func.id_Func;


            if (rdtFeminino.Checked == true || rdtMasculino.Checked == true)
            {
                if (rdtFeminino.Checked == true)
                    funcionario.sexo = "F";
                else
                    funcionario.sexo = "M";
            }


            funcionarioNegocio.InserirFuncionario(funcionario);

            MessageBox.Show("Funcionário cadastrado com sucesso!");

            DialogResult resultado = MessageBox.Show("Deseja Cadastrar outro funcionário?", "Pergunta", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (resultado == DialogResult.No)
                LimparCampos();





        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + erro.Message);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe algo muito mais fácil para recuperar o ultimo registro inserido do que criar uma tabela de depois inserir o registro nela chamado SCOPE_IDENTITY() já respondi isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166759/43340);

Dei uma melhorada na sua proc tinha umas coisas desnecessárias.

```
 ALTER PROC PR_INSERIR_PESSOA_E_FUNCIONARIO
    --pessoas 
    @Cpf varchar(11),
    @Nome varchar(60),
    @sexo char(1),
    --Funcionario
    @funcao varchar(30),
    @IdGerente int,
    @idLoja int
    as  

        --VALIDANDO SE TEM GERENTE CADASTRADO NA LOJA
        IF(@funcao = 'GERENTE') 
        BEGIN    
            DECLARE @CONT INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TblFuncionario WHERE Id_Loja = @idLoja)


        IF(@CONT <= 0)
            BEGIN       

                BEGIN TRAN

                INSERT INTO TblPessoa (Cpf,Nome,Sexo)VALUES (@Cpf,@Nome,@sexo)
                 DECLARE @PessoaId int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                if(@IdGerente = '')
                    set @IdGerente = null;

                INSERT INTO TblFuncionario (Id_Pessoa,Funcao,Id_Gerente,Ativo,Id_Loja, DataContrato)
                VALUES (@PessoaId ,@funcao,@IdGerente,1,@idLoja,GETDATE())

                IF @@ERROR = 0
                    COMMIT
                ELSE
                    ROLLBACK    

                select @PessoaId
            END
        END
    GO
```

Por fim, você tem que rever 3 coisas no seu C#

1º, não execute 3 vezes o mesmo CMD.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

é

```
    try
    {
        idpessoa = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

2º, não a necessidade de você fazer `cmd.Parameters.Clear()`.

3º encerre sua conexão use o [Using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243398/will-a-using-block-close-a-database-connection) por exemplo.