# Procedure de insert em três tabelas

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, stored-procedures

Bom dia a todos estou tentando alterar uma procedure que eu criei para inserir um novo livro em três tabelas a tabelaA tem autoencrement na coluna id_livro, e as tabelas B e C são not null, eu estou usando @@IDENTITY para pegar o último valor de id_livro da tabela A porém ao tentar inserir um livro diz que a coluna id_livro da tabela C não pode aceitar valor nulo, acredito que para tabela C o @@IDENTITY não pega o último valor da tabela anterior alguém poderia me ajudar? e por favor me desculpem se está um pouco confuso sou novo aqui e não sei separar o código do texto.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE adicionarNovoLivro(
@nome_livro varchar(255),
@nome_autor varchar(255),
@ano_livro int,
@nome_editora varchar(100),
@preco_livro float
)

AS


    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosA VALUES(@nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro)
        INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosB VALUES(@@IDENTITY, @nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro)
        INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosC VALUES(@@IDENTITY, @nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro)
    END
```

---

```
EXEC adicionarNovoLivro 'Nome na Taverna', 'Álvarez de Azevedo', 1855, 'Editora Abril', 16.96
```

Comment: Você poderia criar uma variavel, atribuir o valor @@IDENTITY e após adicionar a  variavel aos inserts.

Comment: Bom dia Reginaldo não sei se fiz exatamente como você está propondo mas eu havia tentado fazer isso e também não consegui dá o mesmo erro, funciona o @@IDENTITY somente se eu fizer com duas tabelas ai a segunda o IDENTITY pega o id da anterior com três a terceira tabela fica sem id.

Comment: Tente fazer do modo abaixo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como obter a primary key identity de um registro inserido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166717/como-obter-a-primary-key-identity-de-um-registro-inserido)

Comment: @wilder O nome correto do escritor é **Álvares de Azevedo**.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia criar uma variável, atribuir o valor da @@IDENTITY a variável e usa-la nos inserts.

Assim:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE adicionarNovoLivro(
    @nome_livro varchar(255),
    @nome_autor varchar(255),
    @ano_livro int,
    @nome_editora varchar(100),
    @id_livro int,
    @preco_livro float
    )

    AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosA VALUES(@nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro)
    SELECT @id_livro = @@IDENTITY   
    INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosB VALUES(@id_livro, @nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro)
    INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosC VALUES(@id_livro, @nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro)
END
```

Comment: Funcionou do jeito que você me propôs só que inseriu 7 vezes os mesmos dados nas tabelas.

Comment: Não tem sentido. Você tem um outro problema no seu processo.

Comment: funcionou certinho agora Reginaldo excluir os dados e realizei o procedimento novamente e funcionou corretamente conforme sua dica, eu havia feito algo parecido mas só estava colocando a variável declarada na terceira tabela, mais uma vez fico muito agradecido pela dica tenha um bom dia.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Dica: neste caso, no lugar de @@identity utilize scope_identity()

Comment: vou testar aqui José esse escope_identity() ele faz algo parecido com o @@IDENTITY?

Comment: @wilder A função SCOPE_IDENTITY() retorna o valor que foi gerado no mesmo contexto enquanto que @@IDENTITY pode retornar valor que foi inserido em qualquer contexto. Vide https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a cláusula [`OUTPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) da seguinte forma:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE adicionarNovoLivro(
  @nome_livro varchar(255),
  @nome_autor varchar(255),
  @ano_livro int,
  @nome_editora varchar(100),
  @preco_livro float
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ids TABLE(id INT);
  DECLARE @id INT;

  INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosA
  OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @ids
  VALUES (@nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro);

  SELECT @id = id
    FROM @ids;

  INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosB
  VALUES(@id, @nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro);

  INSERT INTO tbl_LivrosC
  VALUES(@id, @nome_livro, @nome_autor, @ano_livro, @nome_editora, @preco_livro);
END;
GO
```

> [`OUTPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Retorna informações ou expressões baseadas em cada linha afetada por uma instrução `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` ou `MERGE`. Esses resultados podem ser retornados ao aplicativo de processamento para uso em mensagens de confirmação, arquivamentos e outros requisitos similares de aplicativo. Os resultados também podem ser inseridos em uma tabela ou variável de tabela. Além disso, você pode capturar os resultados de uma cláusula `OUTPUT` em uma instrução `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` ou `MERGE` aninhada e inserir esses resultados em uma tabela ou exibição de destino.
>
> **Aplica-se a:** SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 até a versão atual), Banco de dados SQL do Azure.

Comment: Entendi agora ficou mais claro ainda, vou estudar mais e testar a cláusula OUTPUT, muito obrigado mesmo.