# Como inserir dados em uma Tabela N:N

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Estou tendo problemas ao inserir dados em uma tabela N:N. As duas tabelas em questão são: Curso e Matéria. A relação entre eles formam uma tabela chamada `tbMATERIA_CURSO` que armazena as chaves-primaria das duas tabelas.

Código para inserir na tabela `tbCURSO`:

```
Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();

public void insereCurso(string nomeCurso, string periodo, string tipo)
{
    sql.CommandText = "insert into tbCURSO(NomeCurso, Periodo, TipoEnsino) VALUES (@nome_curso, @periodo, @tipoEnsino)";
    // parâmetros
    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome_curso", nomeCurso);
    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@periodo", periodo);
    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoEnsino", tipo);

    try
    {
        sql.Connection = conexao.Conectar();
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexao.Desconectar();
        MessageBox.Show("Curso cadastrado com sucesso", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK , MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    } catch (SqlException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Erro ao tentar se conectar com o Banco de Dados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

Código para inserir na tabela `tbMATERIA`:

```
Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();

public void InsereMaterias(string nomeMateria, int cargaHoraria)
{
    sql.CommandText = "insert into tbMATERIA(NomeMateria, CargaHoraria) VALUES (@nome_materia, @carga_horaria)";
    // parâmetros
    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome_materia", nomeMateria);
    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carga_horaria", cargaHoraria);

    try
    {
        sql.Connection = conexao.Conectar();
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexao.Desconectar();
        MessageBox.Show("Curso cadastrado com sucesso", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Erro ao tentar se conectar com o Banco de Dados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

[image: Relacionamento entre três tabelas: Curso, Matéria e Materia_Curso]

Como eu posso inserir a chave primaria criada na `tbCURSO` e na `tbMATERIA` como chave estrangeira na `tbMATERIA_CURSO`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: Não sei em quê isto me ajuda.

Comment: Como você está utilizando chaves artificiais entendo que sua dificuldade é obter os valores de IdCurso e IdMateria que foram atribuídos no momento da inserção dos registros nas respectivas tabelas para poder fazer a inserção em tbMATERIA_CURSO.

Comment: Cada matéria pode pertencer a um ou mais cursos? Não deveria pertencer apenas a um? Pode existir sim várias matérias com o mesmo nome (mesmo assim acho estranho, mas acredito que possa haver), mas uma pertencer a dois ou mais cursos?

Comment: Sim, por exemplo, a disciplina de língua portuguesa pode está contido em todos os cursos cadastrados, Técnico em Informática, Administração, Contabilidade e etc.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira Uma dica: não use a tag `visual-studio` para perguntas que não forem relacionados à ferramenta propriamente dita (edição de texto, análise de código, plugins, entre outras). Se tiver dúvidas sobre isso, talvez seja uma boa ideia dar uma lida no post [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246)

Answer (score 0):

A sua logica não esta errada vendo do ponto que você pode fazer o CRUD de cada entidade separadamente, ao meu ver o que você pode fazer é criar uma tela onde você possar juntar essas duas entidade e assim fazer o insert na tabela tbMATERIA_CRUSO, informanda suas chaves recuperadas em uma consulta. Geralmente uso um drop draw list para escolher o item da entidade.

Mas existem outas alternativas, como criar uma procedure para gravar as 3 entidade de uma unica vez [recuperando o ID salvo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100115/43340) das principais para usar na intermediaria.

Ou ainda você pode usar da forma que esta fazendo e recuperar o ID de cada uma entidade e criar mais um método recebendo o ID de cada entidade para salvar na tabela tbMATERIA_CRUSO.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a forma mais simples para resolver é criar uma tela onde permita a escolha de ambas tabelas para poder armazenar as chaves na tabela do meio. Por exemplo. Ao cadastrar o curso, você cadastra as disciplinas juntos na mesma interface, ao terminar o cadastro você vai ter o id de ambas tabelas e pode jogar na tabela intermediária.

Ex:

**Tabela Curso**

1|Administração|Noturno|Presencial

**Tabela Materia**

1|Português|60

2|Matematica|90

3|TGA|60

**Tabela MATERIA_CURSO** (Eu mudaria pra curso_materia)

1|1

2|1

3|1

Dependendo de como vai dispor sua interface, pode até fazer em várias telas, sempre guardando o id e passando entre elas. Veja qual opção fica melhor de acordo com seu projeto. Caso queira continuar fazendo em telas separadas ai você cria um método para passar os ids e inserir na tabela M:N